# last three digits and sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the sum of last three digits of the number $89^{23}$
 I arrived to calculate this expression by taking mod 1000.

$89^{23}$ $\mod{1000}$ but what to do next .i stopped . help to sort out this.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519838/last-three-digits-of-23320,   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108868/find-the-last-3-digits-of-the-number-200320022001,   https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-last-three-digits-of-107-107

Comment: You should show your attempts to get a reasonable answer here.

Comment: I m able to get only last two digit like this $89^{23}$ = $9^{23}$ =  ${{9^{2}}^{11}} *9$ =$81^{11}*9$=81*9=29 and unable to get last 3.

Answer (score 2):

$$89^{23}=(90-1)^{23}=-1+\binom{23}190-\binom{23}290^2\pmod{1000}$$

Now $\binom{23}29^2=23\cdot11\cdot81\equiv3\pmod{10}\implies\binom{23}290^2\equiv3\cdot100\pmod{10\cdot100}$

and $\binom{23}190=23\cdot90\equiv2070\equiv70\pmod{1000}$

So,$$89^{23}\equiv-1+70-300\pmod{1000}\equiv-1+70+700\equiv?$$